# Trouble with Infinite sum with constant in exponent

Tags: summation, transformation

In my notes I saw this equation and I can only speculate how it works:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)^{-(n+2)} = \sum^\infty_{k=3}\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)^{-k} $$

The following step $$\sum^\infty_{k=3}\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)^{-k}  = \sum^\infty_{k=3} \left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^k$$ is clear to me but I dont understand the equation above.

Can someone clear this up for me ?

Comment: It is just a substitution: $n = k - 2$.

Comment: or substitution: $k=n+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *both sides* of the first equality unfold to
$$ \Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-3} + \Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-4} + 
\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-5} + \Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-6} + \cdots $$
The terms are just indexed differently:
$$ \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-3}}_{n=1} +
 \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-4}}_{n=2} + 
 \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-5}}_{n=3} +
  \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-6}}_{n=4} + \cdots $$
versus
$$ \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-3}}_{k=3} +
 \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-4}}_{k=4} + 
 \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-5}}_{k=5} +
  \underbrace{\Big(\frac{13}{12}\Big)^{-6}}_{k=6} + \cdots $$